# Azure pipelines - exact .net core version

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am aware we need to download/install a package with .net core 3 before other tasks that use version 3 (build, test...).

What I cant find is, is there a way to have that done automatically so that I don’t have to write a new version into pipelines file every time I have a minor version upgrade in my project?

Comment: you can write a script that reads your project version and then install the package with this version

Comment: @Shayki Abramczyk could you maybe give an example of such a script or point me to some on internet? and please put it in answer so i can upvote/accept it. thanks!

Comment: how you store the version in the project?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk its an `asp.net core web api` project so its in a standard `*.scproj` xml file like: `...<PropertyGroup<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework></PropertyGroup>...`

Comment: I added an example :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a PS that check the version and add it to env varaible:

```
$file = Get-Content path/to/*.scproj
$version = Select-Xml -Content $file -XPath "//TargetFramework"
$doNetCoreVersion = $version.Node.InnerText.Split('app')[3]
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=doNetCoreVersion ;]$doNetCoreVersion"
```

And add a task to install .net core according to the version:

```
steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk'
  inputs:
    packageType: sdk
    version: $(doNetCoreVersion )
    installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet
```